# Range scaling function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

A function returns a value between 0.0 and 1.0. I want now to apply a scaling function on this result so that I get a value between -500 and 500.

The transition should not be linear but adaptable - that is for example I want to achieve that 
a value gets transformed within the range [-500,0] is two more times frequent than within the range [1,500].

I've seen a similar question [Range scaling problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43698/range-scaling-problem) but there a more linear transformation is discussed.

Thanks a lot for any help on this matter!

Comment: If $g(t)$ is your function with values between $0$ and $1$, then you might want the function $1000g(t)^\alpha -500$, where $\alpha$ is an adjustable parameter.

Comment: Yes, thx α = 2 is simply what I need currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently answered in comments:

> If $g(t)$ is your function with values between $0$ and $1$, then you might want the function $1000g(t)^\alpha−500$, where $\alpha$ is an adjustable parameter. – J. M. Apr 28 at 14:54
>
> Yes, thx $\alpha = 2$ is simply what I need currently – Hawk66 Apr 29 at 8:43